# Array by expressions

Tags: php, arrays

In php I have the following variable which comes from a url:

```
$data = "data_id=value1/config/value2/config/value3";
```

It always comes in the following format:

- `data_id` = first value of the parameter to come
- `/ config /` -> which is a kind of parameters tab
- second parameter + `/ config /` + etc ...

I want these values ​​to be inserted into an array, i.e., what would happen is the following:

- The Wrath php gets the variable `$data`, would catch the first parameter, in this case e.g. `value1` (which'll come after the `data_id`) and insert it into the array as a `vector 1`, soon after it takes the `/ config /` and recognizes that it is a separator, thus making it take the `value 2` and enter the array, making this loop until the end.

example:

```
 $data = "data_id =fish/config/horse/config/car";
```

The array will look as follows:

```
array 
{
    [0] -> fish

    [1] -> horse

    [2] -> Car
}
```

could someone help me?

Comment: For all you guys who have answered this question, there are flow on answers to be given over here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734173/undefined-offset-1-array-in-php

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `data_id` is a GET variable, you can do something like this.

```
$data = $_GET['data_id']

$myArray = explode('/config/', $data);
```

[explode() documentation](http://php.net/explode)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = 'data_id=value1/config/value2/config/value3';
list($name, $value) = explode('=', $data, 2);

$result = explode('/config/', $value);
print_r($result);
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/51JAsh)

Comment: Why not get just it from `$_GET`? OP mentioned it was from a URL

Comment: @JustinWood It’s not really clear to me that OP gets that from `$_GET`. But if they are able to get the content as it exists within `$data`, then this is all they need.

Answer (score 0):

If the entire thing is a string you can use `strpos` to get the position of the `=` character and cut it away using `substr`. Then simply explode the entire thing with php `explode`.

```
$data = "data_id =fish/config/horse/config/car";
$data = explode( "/config/", substr( $data, strpos( $data, '=' )+1 ) );
```

Will result in:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
   string(4) "fish"
  [1]=>
   string(5) "horse"
  [2]=>
   string(3) "car"
}
```

[strpos()](http://php.net/strpos)

[substr()](http://php.net/substr)

[explode()](http://php.net/explode)