# Undefined offset 1, array in php

Tags: php

I have this code in JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "funcoes/a-php/ler/ler_config.php",
    data: 'data_id=fish/config/horse/config/car',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data_o){
        alert(data_o);
    }
});
```

and on the file 'ler_config.php' I have this codes:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $data = $_POST['data_id'];
    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $data, 2);
    $result = explode('/config/', $value);
    print_r($result);
}
```

So I'm having trouble with this line:

```
list($name, $value) = explode('=', $data, 2);
```

and php notice me this messanger:

```
Undefined offset 1
```

So how can I fix it?

Comment: Do a print_r($data) to see what is in it and add it to your question to help us answer.

Comment: You aleady have `$_POST['data_id'] = 'fish/config/horse/config/car';`

Comment: Why don't you just combine your two questions into one? You're getting different answers on each question because you haven't provided enough context, now you're chasing a rabbit down a hole... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733720/array-by-expressions

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your explode function is splitting `$data` by `=` signs (which don't exist in the string) - some basic debugging would have told you that.

This is the format of your string:

```
data: 'data_id=fish/config/horse/config/car'
```

... so `$_POST['data_id'] = 'fish/config/horse/config/car';`

Now, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this code, but if you're trying to split that string from AJAX by the `=` sign, you just don't need to. It's just telling ajax that `data_id` is going to be equal to `...`. The `=` doesn't actually come out in PHP.

If you're splitting that string, it should be by `/` instead.

Also, to be clearer with your AJAX, you should wrap your data variables inside `{}` brackets and not include the variable name inside the quotes:

```
data: {
    data_id: 'fish/config/horse/config/car'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your post data: `data_id=fish/config/horse/config/car`
That means that `$_POST['data_id']` will already contain `fish/config/horse/config/car`

Since there is no `=` in it, exploding it will yield an array with only ONE value with index `0`. There will be no second value with index `1`. Thus your message about the index not existing.

So in stead of `list($name, $value) = explode('=', $data, 2);`
... you should do:

```
$name = 'data_id'; // this is the key value you already used for $data
$value = $_POST['data_id']; // or $value = $data; it's the same
```